# How can I replace an element in a cell using javascript? The json is from Progress-4GL DB

Tags: javascript, json, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm new to both Progress and JavaScript. I'm getting elements from a temp-table in Progress using json. I'll show part of my code.

```
$.post({
    url: gWS + "/bass/bass054.p",
    data: {
        "process": "<?php echo $process; ?>"
    },
    success: function(data){

    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var j = 0;
    var dataProc = "";
    var qtProc = 0;
    var item = "";
    var sumQt = 0;
    var qt_total = 0;
    var idGrp = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data["tt-base"].length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(j+2);
        
        if (data["tt-base"][i]["cod_id_bloco_edi"] != idGrp && i>=2) {
            if (sumQt == qt_total) {
                row.style.background = "green";
            } else {
                row.style.background = "#ff0000";
            }
            row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "<b>QT TOTAL:</b>";
            row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "<b>" + item + "</b>";
            row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "<b>" + sumQt + "</b>";
            row.insertCell(3).colSpan = "2";
            row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = "<b>" + qt_total + "</b>";
            sumQt = 0;
            j++;
            row = table.insertRow(j+2);
        }
         if (data["tt-base"][i]["cdn_segment_edi"] == 44) {
            row.style.background = "#00ff00";
            dataProc = data["tt-base"][i]["dsl_dados_entr_edi"].substring(7,9) + "/" + data["tt-base"][i]["dsl_dados_entr_edi"].substring(5,7) + "/20" + data["tt-base"][i]["dsl_dados_entr_edi"].substring(3,5) + "</div>";
            qtProc = parseInt(data["tt-base"][i]["dsl_dados_entr_edi"].substring(11,20), 10) + "</div>";
            row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = dataProc;
            row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = qtProc;
            row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
            row.insertCell(3).colSpan = "2";
            row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = "<div class='p6'>&nbsp;</div>";
            j++;
            sumQt = parseInt(sumQt,10) + parseInt(qtProc,10);
            
        } else if (data["tt-base"][i]["cdn_segment_edi"] == 446) {
            if (data["tt-base"][i]["dsl_dados_entr_edi"].indexOf("PRE") == 10) {
                document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(j+1);
                j--;
                row = table.insertRow(j+2);
                row.style.background = "#0099CC";
                row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = dataProc;
                row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = qtProc;
                row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "PREVIS";
                row.insertCell(3).colSpan = "2";
                row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = "<div class='p6'>&nbsp;</div>";
                dataProc = '';
                qtProc = 0;
                j++;
                
            } else if (data["tt-base"][i]["dsl_dados_entr_edi"].indexOf("FIR") == 10) {
                document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(j+1);
                j--;
                row = table.insertRow(j+2);
                row.style.background = "#00ff00";
                row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = dataProc;
                row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = qtProc;
                row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "FIRM";
                row.insertCell(3).colSpan = "2";
                row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = "<div class='p6'>&nbsp;</div>";
                dataProc = '';
                qtProc = 0;
                j++;
                
            }
        }
        
        idGrp = data["tt-base"][i]["cod_id_bloco_edi"];
    }
}
}).fail(function() {
    alert("Not Possible.");
})
```

So, instead of deleting the row as I'm doing it now I'd like to replace the previous only the cells with the FIRM and PREVIS. I tried using only `row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "PREVIS";` but it didn't work correctly.
Is there any suggestion as to how can I do it? Sorry if I'm not clear enough as i'm new to all this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted after tweaking for hours, lol.
Instead of using insertRow or insertCell, I just used the following

```
table.rows[j+2].style.background = "#0099CC";
table.rows[j+2].cells[2].innerHTML = "PREVIS";
```

This way, I was able to replace the content of what I wanted. I still have to change some other details, but the most difficult part is finally gone. Sorry if I wasted your time, but writing here has helped me to see the code in a different angle. I hope my code can help other people.